# How to get client's access method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp

I have a web application with sping-mvc and I want to get access method of client, whether it is browse directly through my domain or a link on Facebook, Google search... Result should be something likes a URL such as www.mydomain.com or www.google.com , or anything that points out client’s access method.
Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: You can read the headers and get the origin.

Comment: A URL is not an 'access method'. If you want a URL, say so.

Answer (score 0):

In the controller, you can take the HttpServletRequest as a parameter and get the origin from the header as :

```
String origin = request.getHeader("Origin");
```

The origin will return: www.mydomain.com if that URL/API is accessed from your domain or another domain if your URL /API are accessed from another domain like Facebook

Demo Method:

```
    public ResponseEntity<Foo> getFoo(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String origin = request.getHeader("Origin");
    System.out.println(origin);
}
```

Comment: Never use `getHeader` in Spring MVC. Use `@RequestHeader` instead.